# How to attach a sql db with blobs using a shared folder?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, remote, filestream

I use the following query for attaching a `sql db`:

```
CREATE DATABASE [myDb] ON 
 (FILENAME=N'C:\myDb\myDb.mdf'),
 (FILENAME=N'C:\myDb\myDb_log.ldf'),
 (FILENAME=N'C:\myDb\FILESTORE')
FOR ATTACH
```

In general it works well. I have a bit complicated case. I have to use a `shared folder` for attaching my db. I create a `shared folder` using the following command:

```
net share myShare=C:\myDb
```

Attaching a db from `shared folder` works well until the db doesn't have `blobs`.
If db has `blobs` `sql` returns the following error:

```
The path '\\localhost\myShare\FILESTORE' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files. For information about supported paths, see SQL Server Books Online.
Msg 5135, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
The path '\\localhost\myShare\FILESTORE' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files. For information about supported paths, see SQL Server Books Online.
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 2
Unable to open the physical file "\\localhost\myShare\FILESTORE". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7, Line 2
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

The sort of workaround for this problem is creating a `symbolic link` for `blob folder`.

```
mklink /D "C:\slink_myDb" "\\localhost\myShare"
```

and then

```
CREATE DATABASE [myDb] ON 
 (FILENAME=N'\\localhost\myShare\myDb.mdf.mdf'),
 (FILENAME=N'\\localhost\myShare\myDb_log.ldf'),
 (FILENAME=N'C:\slink_myDb\FILESTORE')
FOR ATTACH
```

It works with almost all `sql` servers but it looks like since `sql server 2016` it was disabled. `sql server 2016` returns this:

```
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 106, Line 9
Unable to open the physical file "C:\slink_myDb\FILESTORE". Operating system error -1073741766: "0xc000003a(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 317)".
Msg 5105, Level 16, State 14, Line 9
A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'C:\slink_myDb\FILESTORE' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
Could not open new database 'myDb'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
```

How to attach a sql db with blobs via unc paths ?
(without copying; db files are local, sql server is remote)

ps
All needed permission `ntfs` and sharing are granted.
I've tried `fsutil`

```
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2L:1 R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1
```

Comment: Are you not running this in an unsupported configuration by using the symbolic links?

Comment: @George.Palacios yes I am.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not supported to use "localhost"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-with-smb-fileshare-as-a-storage-option?view=sql-server-2017

You may need to use another server instead of localhost.

Comment: I've double checked it. Yes, it's true that you shouldn't use localhost(tested in sql 14 and 16). But anyway the problem is different. I have 2 pretty the same cases except sql servers are different(2014 and 2016) and with sql 2014 a db can be attached but with sql 2016 I can't attach the same db.